# Transfer local git repo on Mac

Tags: windows, macos, git, shared, repository

I am working on an iOS project. I just created a local repo for my project on Mac. Due to some reasons, I have to transfer it to a windows machine to place it a shared folder. I do not have access to that shared drive from my Mac.

How do I proceed with creating a repo that can be shared? I am at a point where I have all my code committed in local repo. Please advice..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few possibilities:

- Just copy the repo to a USB key or external disc, and then transfer to the PC. Git repos can always be transferred, you do not need to do anything special: the on-disk format is always the same. Although you may encounter some issues with file encoding (Windows or UTF-8): it would be good to configure both gits to use UTF-8. Optionally you can zip your repo folder and unzip it on the PC.
- Upload to dropbox or similar file transfer service. Same as above.
- Share the code on github or a similar public git service. This is by far the best option, although (if the code is not under an open source license) it may cost you money. Upload to github, download from the PC.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the options. I would like to go with the first option. Now, if I place it directly in the shared drive, then will others be able to clone/pull it from the shared drive? I did not do any of the follwoing commands - "git clone --bare .." or "git remote add origin .." until now. Do I need to go through any configuration steps after moving the project to the windows machine?

Comment: You do not need the repo to be bare to clone it. You do, however, need a bare repo to push safely to it. See this post: http://www.bitflop.com/document/111